# Vim crashes when used with Conda Python3 on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, vim, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to have Python27 and Python34 support for the compiled 64bit version of VIM (used MSVS 2013 to compile it) on my Windows 7 machine (64bit too). I'm using [Conda 64bit](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda) Python distribution where Python27 is the main installation (I also have it in my Windows PATH) and Python34 was installed as a separate environment. `Python27.dll` and `Python34.dll` files were placed into the VIM's directory.

```
:version
```

shows that my VIM installation has support for both Python distributions, but when I try to run:

```
py3 print('test')
```

GVIM just crashes and VIM provides the following error message:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

`py print('test')` works fine.

I reproduced the same behaviour with [Haroogan's](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-for-windows) VIM installation.

Is there any way to tell VIM to use both Python distributions?

Comment: You want some command that changes the PATH based on which one you want to use.

Comment: I tried to have something like that in my vimrc: `:command! Py3 !$Python3Location %` but it didn't help. Looks like the official Python installation package has a tool that will select proper Python based on the command...but I really like conda at this point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this based on `asmeurer's` suggestion and added the following code to my `.vimrc` file:

```
if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_win32")
    :command! Python3 !activate py3k %
    :command! Py3 !activate py3k %
  endif
endif
```

where `py3k` is Python3 virtual environment, i.e.:

```
conda create -n py3k python=3
```

**UPDATE (03/02/2015)**
Didn't quite work as I expected, as VIM would still crash from time to time. I ended up installing official Python 2/3 distributions along with my Conda.
I also deleted extra `command` lines from my `vimrc` file.